# How to use Storage facade to delete a file

Tags: laravel, file, facade

I'm able to delete the image from the local driver using the below logic when I use php unlink method but when I use Storage facade the post get's deleted but the image is not deleted. I've tried playing around with the Facade way but I can't seem to have it work. What I'm I missing?

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        // unlink('storage/'.$post->imagePath);
        Storage::delete('storage/'.$post->imagePath);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('flash', 'Post Deleted Successfully');

    }
```

Comment: Dont pass `storage/` in delete method. Storage facade id automatically working with files in `storage` directory.

Comment: I tried ```Storage::delete($post->imagePath);``` before passing storage/ but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that (by default), the `Storage` facade looks into `/your/project/storage/app`.

This is the `root` directory.

If we assume:

- Your project is located in `/home/alphy/my-project`
- `$post->imagePath == 'posts/18/picture.png'`

... then:

- All `Storage` facade methods, including `delete()`, `copy()`, `path()`... will looks for `/home/alphy/my-project/storage/app/posts/18/picture.png` when you give them `$post->imagePath`

So:

```php
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        Storage::delete('storage/'.$post->imagePath);
        // tries to delete /home/alphy/my-project/storage/app/storage/$post->imagePath     
        // which is probably wrong   


        $post->delete();
        return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('flash', 'Post Deleted Successfully');

    }
```

Comment: Makes sense, my images is in ``` /home/alphy/my-project/storage/app/public/postImages/uniqueIdofTheImage```

```my $post->imagePath``` is ```postImages/uniqueIdofTheImage```

Any idea how to work around it or how to override the default path?

Comment: Everything is configured inside `config/filesystem.php`. However, if the image is in `storage/app/public`, then you can simple do `Storage::disk('public')->delete('postImages/uniqueIdofTheImage')`

Comment: Works, and all clear to me now... thank you!